# How to get text from input tag?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've a case where I've to get the text from `input` tag which is something like -

```
<input id="AB_WIN_1" class="text real" type="text" ds="0" style="top:0px; left:167px; width:140px; height:21px;"/>
```

And the text in that input tag is some text say `Hello`

But when I use `getText`, it returns nothing.

Is there anyway I can get text from `input` tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use any of the below:

```
1. element.getAttribute("value")
2. element.getAttribute("innerHTML")
3. element.getAttribute("innerText")
4. element.getText()
5. ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)execute.script("return arguments[0].value",element)
```

Let me know if this does not helps.

Comment: anytime..np..though javascript is never recommended but sometimes thats what does the magic for us

Answer (score 1):

use `element.getAttribute("value")`. getText can not extract input value.

Comment: There is no attribute which stores the value.